# I want to distribute rows in one table to rows in other table that can take equally number row in SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a SQL query that will distribute records from one table to another table that take equally number.

In this example I have two tables, `Students` and `Teachers`, and I want to assign Students to each Teacher.

Students: (Adam ,Bennet, Elmer ,Justin ,Louis ,Noah,Jack)

Teachers: (Leo,Kyle,Ethan)

Notice:

1. one student cannot have more than one teacher
2. each teacher should have same number of students as any other teacher ...
3. ... unless the number of students is not an exact multiple of the number of teachers in which case students must be as evenly divided between teachers as possible

For instance, if we have seven students and three teachers the first two teachers will take two students and the last one will take three students.

Result:

```
Student | Teacher
--------+--------
Adam    | Leo
Bennet  | Leo
Elmer   | Kyle
Justin  | Kyle
Louis   | Ethan
Noah    | Ethan
Jack    | Ethan
```

How can i do that in Oracle SQL?

also : if I want to add courses and the student must have different teacher in different coerces  ... result :

```
Student | Teacher | coerces 
--------+---------+---------
Adam    | Leo     |  1
Bennet  | Leo     |  1
Elmer   | Kyle    |  1
Justin  | Kyle    |  1
Louis   | Ethan   |  1
Noah    | Ethan   |  1
Jack    | Ethan   |  1
Louis   | Leo     |  2
Noah    | Leo     |  2
Jack    | Kyle    |  2
Adam    | Kyle    |  2
Bennet  | Ethan   |  2
Elmer   | Ethan   |  2
Justin  | Ethan   |  2
```

how i can do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will not necessarily distribute the Teachers in the order you wished, but will do it proportionately as you wished nonetheless. It uses the `NTILE` function to put names into buckets and assigns the appropriate bucket number to each row.

If you wish to have an order, you must include a unique Id column for both teachers and students.

```
with tch as
(
 select t.*, row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY name ) as n from teachers t
 ),
ct AS
 ( 
  select count(*) as cnt from Teachers
  )
 select s.name as student,tch.name as teacher from
 (

     SELECT name, NTILE(cnt) OVER (partition by cnt ORDER BY name)  AS n 
         FROM Students cross join
       ct
) s join tch on tch.n = s.n;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=273e5410e9abc596ef7db29adad09c57)

```
 Student| Teacher 
 -----  | ----
 Adam   | Ethan
 Bennet | Ethan
 Elmer  | Ethan
 Jack   | Kyle 
 Justin | Kyle 
 Louis  | Leo  
 Noah   | Leo
```

Answer (score 2):

One method: Number students and teachers. Then join using modulo where the divisor is the number of teachers:

```
select
  s.name as student,
  t.name as teacher
from (select name, row_number() over(order by name) as rn from teachers) t
join (select name, row_number() over(order by name) as rn from students) s
  on mod(s.rn - 1, (select count(*) from teachers)) = t.rn -1
order by teacher, student;
```

Comment: if I want to add courses and the student must have different teacher in different coerces result :                                                                                      
Student | Teacher | coerces 
--------+---------+---------
Adam    | Leo     |  1
Bennet  | Leo     |  1
Elmer   | Kyle    |  1
Justin  | Kyle    |  1
Louis   | Ethan   |  1
Noah    | Ethan   |  1
Jack    | Ethan   |  1
Louis   | Leo     |  2
Noah    | Leo     |  2
Jack    | Kyle    |  2
Adam    | Kyle    |  2
Bennet  | Ethan   |  2
Elmer   | Ethan   |  2
Justin  | Ethan   |  2
how can do it?